# Error while install Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Have install and Configure Joomla 1.5 CMS in my local xampp.

After I have installing,

When i am visiting to Joomla Site. it displaying the some error messages.

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 29

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 32

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::clean() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 33

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 463

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 464

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 465

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 466

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 467

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 468

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 35

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 38

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 39

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 46

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 47

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 50

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 53

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 54

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 57

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 58

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getApplication() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\index.php on line 31

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class JObject in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\base\object.php on line 57

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplication::getInstance() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 46

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplicationHelper::getClientInfo() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\application\application.php on line 132

Strict Standards: Declaration of JSite::getRouter() should be compatible with that of JApplication::getRouter() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\includes\application.php on line 377

Strict Standards: Declaration of JSite::getPathWay() should be compatible with that of JApplication::getPathway() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\includes\application.php on line 377

Strict Standards: Declaration of JSite::getMenu() should be compatible with that of JApplication::getMenu() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\includes\application.php on line 377

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getConfig() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\application\application.php on line 732

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::_createConfig() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 73

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\registry\registry.php on line 19

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JUtility::getHash() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\application\application.php on line 101

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getConfig() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\utilities\utility.php on line 111

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getConfig() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\application\application.php on line 384

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getSession() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\application\application.php on line 770

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::_createSession() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 94

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getConfig() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 501

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Declaration of JSession::set() should be compatible with that of JObject::set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\session\session.php on line 737

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\session\session.php on line 19

Strict Standards: Non-static method JSession::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 507

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JSessionStorage::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\session\session.php on line 108

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFilterInput::clean() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\session\storage.php on line 57

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getDBO() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\session\storage\database.php on line 64

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getConfig() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 268

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::_createDBO() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 271

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getConfig() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 551

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JDatabase::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 563

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JError::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 565

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JTable::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\joomla\session\storage\database.php on line 69

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\libraries\loader.php on lin
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Strict Standards" isn't technically an error, it's saying that the Joomla version you installed isn't strictly adhering to PHP standards. What you want to do is two things: first, restrict error reporting in php.ini to not report a standards violation as an error, then (when you're ready for go-live), turn off Joomla error reporting.

In your php.ini, change
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
to
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

Restart xampp to apply the changes.

In Joomla's configuration.php file, change $error_reporting value to 6135.

Comment: I am facing same error ! but your solution doesn't help me :(

Answer (score 10):

Thank Guys. I have found the Solution

You need to deactivate the display of PHP errors and warnings from your php.ini.
You could contact your hosting provider about it or you could do it yourself ( if you have access to that file ).

If you not have access to the php.ini file you can try to edit your htaccess file. (You find this file in the root of your Joomla! installation. If the name is htaccess.txt, remember to rename it to .htaccess .

Write this to your .htaccess file

**Code**

```
# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? This might be due to using PHP 5.3 with Joomla 1.5 (which pre-dates 5.3, and isn't really built for it).

Comment: @KingJackaL most of the MAMP/WAMP/XAMPP bundles are preconfigured with PHP 5.3, more or less with the default configuration. And as you mention, while Joomla 1.5 was patched for 5.3, it wasn't necessarily designed for it.

Comment: I have tried to found out, which changes one should do at least in "php.ini" to make it work. So they are: "php_flag display_startup_errors off" and "php_flag display_errors off". It worked by me!

Answer (score 1):

In xampp/php/php.ini change

```
    1.display_errors=Off
    2.error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING
```

Then restart your xampp

Answer (score 0):

Set error reporting to "none" in joomla configuration. which will turn off notices