# Joomla website throwing errors

Tags: php, joomla

Sometime back, I had created a Joomla website on a third-party server. Now when I try to access the website, I'm seeing errors such as the following:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /home/chinfote/public_html/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 29

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /home/chinfote/public_html/libraries/loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /home/chinfote/public_html/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 32

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /home/chinfote/public_html/libraries/loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in /home/chinfote/public_html/libraries/loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /home/chinfote/public_html/libraries/loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::clean() should not be called statically in /home/chinfote/public_html/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 33

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/chinfote/public_html/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 463
```

After searching on the net, I found that I should be making some changes in the php.ini file. But on the File Manager of the cpanel, I could not find this file. 
Could anyone please help me in finding this file and solving these errors.
Or is there any other way to solve the above problem??

Many thanks in advance.

~Jahnavi

Comment: There are some hosting companies who don't provide access to php.ini. Furthermore, I think you want to turn off error reporting which should be done in the first place on a production environment, contact your hosting company for this matter. By the way I think you can turn off error reporting in Joomla administration panel.

Comment: You can turn off the error reporting in the global configuration in the joomla backend or ask you host to disable strict error reporting

Comment: I'm not even able to access the Joomla backend. The same errors on this as well. When contacted the hosting company, they said that they cannot solve coding issues. :( Will try again though. Thanks. Please let me know if there's anything else I could do.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV On asking the hosting company, they said Since the php version as been upgraded to 5.4.11 I have to visit the joomla forum and re configure your web site. Any idea how I can do this??

Comment: It's not a coding issue. Just edit configuration.php to lower the error reporting.  If you upgrade to a current version of joomla you won't have this problem.

Comment: Please Refer to this thread,Solution is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771128/error-while-install-joomla

Answer (score 10):

Joomla 1.5 work in PHP 5.4.

You can paste this code **index.php** for frontend and backend. It works for me!

// Set flag that this is a parent file

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

error_reporting( E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING );
```

Answer (score 7):

Suppressing the warnings is **not the same thing as fixing them**.

Joomla might might have a lot of functionality built-in but it's security history is far from exemplory. Have you got the latest version of Joomla installed? If not, then do so now. If you are still getting warnings then [report it as a bug](http://forum.joomla.org/viewforum.php?f=199).

Comment: you should upgrade your joomla version.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered same issue, my configuration was Joomla 1.5 on shared hosting server.

However the hosting provider upgraded PHP Version to 5.4 from 5.2 . It seems that Joomla 1.5 is not compatible with PHP Version 5.4, so instead of supressing your errors (which of course is not a nice idea) try adjusting the PHP Version on your shared hosting/ or dedicated hosting...

Cheers. If there is a warning do not hide it - resolve it...!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

unbelievable.
you people are obviously not coders if all you are trying to do is to HIDE the message.
Messages are there for a reason.
find the function in your component and put the word static in front of it.
function import(
change to static function import(

Problem solved. not hidden

Comment: And that is what the answer with the most votes is saying. So what is your point of repeating that?

Answer (score 0):

You will find it in (for linux) /etc/php.ini

Try this: Replace 
display_errors = On --> display_errors = Off

error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT --> error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

Comment: Or is there just any other way I could solve the above problem??

Comment: Have you put your website in a shared server? or do you have a dedicated server which you can get connected to using ssh

Comment: Log in as admin, In the top menu, click Global Configuration then PHP Information tab.
Scroll down the list of php settings until you find the Loaded Configuration File setting. The Loaded Configuration File will show the path to the php.ini file your Joomla website is using.

    Try to access to this file, if you don't have the right to do it, try to turn off error reporting in the global configuration

Comment: The website is on a shared server. Apparently, I cant even login as admin as the admin page too throws the above errors :( I am only able to login to the cpanel

Comment: Try to host your site in wamp (in localhost) and tell me what happens

Answer (score 0):

If there are no php.ini file in your joomla root directory make a new phi.ini file in using Cpanel ( create a new file ) and do you stuff with it

Comment: How can I find the joomla root directory using the cpanel? Sorry for the silly questions, its the first time I've created a website.

Comment: Can u see some files in the public_html folder ?

Comment: Yes, I did the following:  Navigated to public_html -> libraries -> joomla and created a file named php.ini in this folder and added the following lines there: display_errors = Off and error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE . But on refreshing my web page, the errors are still seen there :(

Comment: If you have access to php.ini
set the display_errors directive to Off

If you don't have access to php.ini

error_reporting(0); in your code

Answer (score 0):

Switch your php version to php 5.3

also change the error_reporting in your joomla configuration file (configuration.php)

```
var $error_reporting = '6143';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem only if you return to php 5.2 or you will change the new version to work with J 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Two things to address and surpass the errors 
1. set error reporting to none in configuration
2. Your joomla version may be old ,

Answer (score 0):

You can paste this code index.php for administrator and frontend.

// Set flag that this is a parent file

```
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

error_reporting( E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING );
```

Answer (score -1):

Some hosters don't allow the PHP.ini to be read from the root of the folder. But if they do, you may need to add another one for your /administrator folder.  This may at least let you get into the backend.  If not, you may be able to set these PHP parameters through your htaccess file.  Might need a little more google searching but there should be plenty of info on it...

Answer (score -1):

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called
statically in /home/chinfote/public_html/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 29
```

You will find it in `server.. /etc/php.ini`

Try this: Replace `display_errors = On` To  `display_errors = Off`

Answer (score -1):

Just do as follows in php.ini file:

```
;error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add these lines to your .htacces file ; if your only problem is shown errors.

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```